# Spring Batch - execute Steps based on decisions issue

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm developing **Spring Batch** where I've `Steps-1` to `Step-10` which runs sequentially. In my case for step-4 to Step-7, I've to make conditional decision based on which I've execute `Step-X, Step-Y` and , `Step-Z` etc.

Ex: Step-4 - Precondition, if `Step-X` gives any status other than error, then execute `Step-4`, if `Step-X` failed then execute `failedStep()` step.

Step-5 - Precondition, if `Step-Y` gives any status other than error, then execute `Step-5`, if `Step-Y` failed then execute `failedStep()` step.

Step-6 - Precondition, if `Step-Z` gives any status other than error, then execute `Step-6`, if `Step-z` failed then execute `failedStep()` step and the  `step-8` to `step-10`. I'm looking to do all in a single batch job only.

I've developed some code, but it looks like it's not liking the condition.

> Error - The method on(String) is undefined for the type Step

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return steps.get("step1")
                .tasklet((StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("Step1");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return steps.get("step2")
                .tasklet((StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("step2");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step3() {
        return steps.get("step3")
                .tasklet((StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("step3");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step step4() {
        return steps.get("step4")
                .tasklet((StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("step4");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public Step step5() {
        return steps.get("step5")
                .tasklet((StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("step5");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepX() {
        return steps.get("stepX")
                .tasklet((StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("step4Check");
                    // int update = jdbcTemplate.update("Query", "SBC"); // Perform some meaningful DB operations
                    int update = 1; // To simulate issue locally !
                    if(update == 1) {
                        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("COMPLETED"));
                    }else {
                        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("FAILED"));
                    }
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepY() {
        return steps.get("stepY")
                .tasklet((StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("step4Check");
                    // int update = jdbcTemplate.update("Query", "XYZ"); // Perform some meaningful DB operations
                    int update = 1; // To simulate issue locally !
                    if(update == 1) {
                        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("COMPLETED"));
                    }else {
                        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("FAILED"));
                    }
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step failedStep() {
        return steps.get("failedStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .next(step3())
                .next(stepX().on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(failedStep())
                .from(stepX()).on("*").to(step4())
                
                .from(stepY()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(failedStep())
                .from(stepY()).on("*").to(step5())
                .build();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I was not able to follow your flow definition from all these conditions in text format. Can you post a diagram similar to https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - I've added the flow, could you please guide ? I am looking to do all this in single job (if possible).

Comment: I just saw your update, thank you. A picture is worth a thousand words! Glad to see you were able to implement your flow as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using following code - This works perfectly fine for me.

**Approach-1**

```
@Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .next(step3()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(failedStep())
                .from(step3()).on("*").to(stepX())
                
                .from(stepX()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(failedStep())
                .from(stepX()).on("*").to(step4())

                .from(step4()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(failedStep())
                .from(step4()).on("*").to(stepY())

                .from(stepY()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(failedStep())
                .from(stepY()).on("*").to(step5())
                .next(step6())
                .build()
                .build();
    }
```

**Approach-2**

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobs.get("job")
            .start(step1())
            .next(step2())
            .next(step3())
            .next(stepX()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(failedStep())
            .from(stepX()).on("*").to(step4())

            .next(stepY()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(failedStep())
            .from(stepY()).on("*").to(step5())
            .next(step6())
            .build()
            .build();
}
```